# How to get and & of list of pandas indexes

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing

OK, kind of an interesting special case here (I think)

I have a dataframe which contains multiple columns of flags.  I have multiple cases where some flags might not be available ( hardware units may not exist in some configurations)

What I want is to find the valid indices of all of the *existing* rows.

So my thought was to make a list of the indices and somehow "and" or "or" them together in order to get the index that I want.  However how to do this is very unclear.

Here is an example code: (with example, this code will run correctly)

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'datetime': {0: '07/06/2022 12:09', 1: '07/06/2022 12:09', 2: '07/06/2022 12:09', 3: '07/06/2022 12:09', 4: '07/06/2022 12:09', 5: '07/06/2022 12:09', 6: '07/06/2022 12:09', 7: '07/06/2022 12:09', 8: '07/06/2022 12:09', 9: '07/06/2022 12:09', 10: '07/06/2022 12:09', 11: '07/06/2022 12:09', 12: '07/06/2022 12:09', 13: '07/06/2022 12:09'}, 'flag1': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: True, 8: True, 9: True, 10: False, 11: False, 12: False, 13: False}, 'flag2': {0: False, 1: False, 2: True, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: True, 8: False, 9: False, 10: False, 11: False, 12: False, 13: False}, 'flag3': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: False, 8: False, 9: False, 10: False, 11: False, 12: False, 13: False}, 'flag4': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: True, 8: True, 9: True, 10: False, 11: False, 12: False, 13: False}, 'value1': {0: 179.012, 1: 179.012, 2: 179.012, 3: 179.012, 4: 179.012, 5: 179.012, 6: 179.012, 7: 179.012, 8: 179.012, 9: 179.012, 10: 179.012, 11: 179.012, 12: 179.012, 13: 179.012}, 'value2': {0: -101.39, 1: -101.39, 2: -101.41, 3: -101.39, 4: -101.43, 5: -101.43, 6: -101.43, 7: -101.46, 8: -101.4, 9: -101.39, 10: -101.39, 11: -101.43, 12: -101.43, 13: -101.38}, 'state': {0: 'IDLE', 1: 'ON', 2: 'ON', 3: 'ON', 4: 'ACTIVE', 5: 'ACTIVE', 6: 'ACTIVE', 7: 'ACTIVE', 8: 'ACTIVE', 9: 'ACTIVE', 10: 'ACTIVE', 11: 'ACTIVE', 12: 'IDLE', 13: 'IDLE'}})

#the valid indexes
validrx = []

if 'flag1' in df.columns:
      item1 = (df['flag1'] == True)
      if item1.any(): 
            validrx.append(item1)
if 'flag2' in df.columns:
      item2 = (df['flag2'] == True)
      if item2.any(): 
            validrx.append(item1)
if 'flag3' in df.columns:
      item3 = (df['flag3'] == True)
      if item3.any(): 
            validrx.append(item1)
if 'flag4' in df.columns:
      item4 = (df['flag4'] == True)
      if item4.any(): 
            validrx.append(item1)
# validrx now contains list of valid flags
# a full test would validate that the below functions work with some items missing!

#this does what I want, but only if all of the items exist and have a true value.
whenAllAreTrueAtTheSameTime = df[item1 & item2 & item3 & item4]

#give me all of the valid indexes for all the values that *have a true value*
whenAllAreTrueAtTheSameTime = df[(do something AND with validrx here)]

#this does what I want, but only if all of the items exist and have a true value.
whenAnyareTrueAtTheSameTime = df[(item1 | item2 | item3 | item4)]

#how do I do this too?
whenAnyareTrueAtTheSameTime = df[(do something OR with validrx here)]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe?

Comment: Added an example dataframe that works, Though I haven't figured out why my OR example doesn't work but the AND example does...

Comment: HI, what does `do something OR with validrx here` means? It would be easier to help if you could show what the expected result looks like, given the toy dataframe you provided. Cheers.

Comment: Basically each of the flags exists in a TRUE state for some time, but a different length of time.  I want to get the start and stop of the "ALL ON" (AND of all 4 flags) and the "ANY ON" (OR of all 4 flags) cases.  When all 4 flags are present in the database (and valid) this is easy.  However I have a case were some of the flags can sometimes not show up.  (ie 1,2, or 3 of 4 flags are in the DB) .. I will try to add an output example.

Comment: It just occurred to me after this last response that perhaps if I just manually add the missing columns as NULL values to the dataframe then the OR case will work correctly.. however it will not work for the AND case.

Comment: OK, I made a fix so that the df definition works correctly (forgot to build from dict) -> Now after validrx is created, there are 4 statements.  The first and third work correctly *if all 4 items are present*  -> What I am trying to do is determine how to make statements 2 and 4 work when not all flags are present in the database.

Comment: Note that I could certainly create all of the different cases (if only flag1 then only check flag1, if flag1 and flag2 check item1 and item2.. however this is what I am basically trying to avoid.. manually writing 16 different test cases.

Comment: I also now have thought of an alternative approach:  Find the start time and end time for each flag and then make a combined set of incidences and get the datafame from that output...   Anyone have any more Pythonic ideas??

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I found *A* solution to my problem.  However I did not answer my question.

I am still wondering if there is a more PYTHONIC way to do this... so anyone who comes up with a better answer is welcome to try!

Note that instead of trying to brute force get the answer from the dataframe I just extracted the start and stop times of each case and then got the mins and maxes of each one in order to answer the final question.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'datetime': {0: '07/06/2022 12:09', 1: '07/06/2022 12:09', 2: '07/06/2022 12:09', 3: '07/06/2022 12:09', 4: '07/06/2022 12:09', 5: '07/06/2022 12:09', 6: '07/06/2022 12:09', 7: '07/06/2022 12:09', 8: '07/06/2022 12:09', 9: '07/06/2022 12:09', 10: '07/06/2022 12:09', 11: '07/06/2022 12:09', 12: '07/06/2022 12:09', 13: '07/06/2022 12:09'}, 'flag1': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: True, 8: True, 9: True, 10: False, 11: False, 12: False, 13: False}, 'flag2': {0: False, 1: False, 2: True, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: True, 8: False, 9: False, 10: False, 11: False, 12: False, 13: False}, 'flag3': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: False, 8: False, 9: False, 10: False, 11: False, 12: False, 13: False}, 'flag4': {0: False, 1: False, 2: False, 3: True, 4: True, 5: True, 6: True, 7: True, 8: True, 9: True, 10: False, 11: False, 12: False, 13: False}, 'value1': {0: 179.012, 1: 179.012, 2: 179.012, 3: 179.012, 4: 179.012, 5: 179.012, 6: 179.012, 7: 179.012, 8: 179.012, 9: 179.012, 10: 179.012, 11: 179.012, 12: 179.012, 13: 179.012}, 'value2': {0: -101.39, 1: -101.39, 2: -101.41, 3: -101.39, 4: -101.43, 5: -101.43, 6: -101.43, 7: -101.46, 8: -101.4, 9: -101.39, 10: -101.39, 11: -101.43, 12: -101.43, 13: -101.38}, 'state': {0: 'IDLE', 1: 'ON', 2: 'ON', 3: 'ON', 4: 'ACTIVE', 5: 'ACTIVE', 6: 'ACTIVE', 7: 'ACTIVE', 8: 'ACTIVE', 9: 'ACTIVE', 10: 'ACTIVE', 11: 'ACTIVE', 12: 'IDLE', 13: 'IDLE'}})

flag1 = 'flag1'
flag2 = 'flag2'
flag3 = 'flag3'
flag4 = 'flag4'

# test cases
# df.drop('flag1', axis = 1,inplace=True)
# df.drop('flag2', axis = 1,inplace=True)
# df.drop('flag3', axis = 1,inplace=True)
# df.drop('flag4', axis = 1,inplace=True)

#the valid indexes
valstart = []
valend = []

flaglist = [flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4]
curflag = flag1
for curflag in flaglist:
      if curflag in df.columns and (df[curflag] == True).any():
            #find the start and end of the case
            valstart.append(df[(df[curflag] == True)].index[0])
            valend.append(df[(df[curflag] == True)].index[-1])

anystart = min(valstart)
allstart = max(valstart)
anyend = max(valend)
allend = min(valend)

whenAllAreTrueAtTheSameTime = df[allstart:allend+1]
whenAnyareTrueAtTheSameTime  = df[anystart:anyend+1]
```